# How do I force html page to end before Safari bottom panel?

Tags: html, css, safari

So I am relatively new to this. But I noticed that my page looks differently in Safari and Chrome mobile.

[image]

(These red lines are just lines on the picture)

It seems Safari scales my picture more than Chrome and because of that all content is moved.

So, how should I code this situation so it looks more similar in both browsers? The thing is I want to make a slide-show so I need notes to be bound to the images.

My MWE:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=1">
</head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: visible;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 76px;
}
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.container {
    height: 100vh;
}
.slide {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 120px 0;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
</style>
<body>     
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="slide" style="background-image:url(./images/bg01.jpg)" >
                Love                                            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the property defined in your css:

```
 .container {
     background-size: cover;
 }
```

The devices are not the identical in height, so it needs to manipulate the image to "cover" the screen area as the size of the device increases or decreases.

Your best bet is to use a fixed height for the image or page.

You can learn about full page backgrounds here:

https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Device is the same. It works absolutely in the same way in all mobile browsers except Safari.

Comment: But I guess it still can be considered as a different device. But still the thing is safari scales image like it puts the end of image to be (!)below botbar so we can scroll behind it... while others just cover with image (!)until bot-bar

Comment: @Lust_For_Love My mistake, I thought they were different devices, but you're correct the different browsers do technically have different dimensions which cause the CSS to react this way. Honestly there are always nuances like this between browsers which force us to use things such as media queries, or defining styling for specific browsers. What are the dimensions of the image you are using?

Comment: The thing is I use slide-show in my own html-code. Imade this minimal working example just to show the problem. So I have many images with different dimentions... and I didnt think it should matter since I'm using 'background-size: cover;'. Well, this image is 2581x1936.

Once again, only safari has this problem sinse it associates end of the page with bottom of the screen and then hides some content of the page with bottom-bar. Other mobile browsers (like MobileChrome) associates end of the page with (!)beginning of bottom-bar. So it's a bit higher than bottom of the screen.

Comment: Also if 'overflow:hidden' used... Safari would cut content which hidden behind its bottom-bar in this case.